# Xamarin.Form is not found in Reference dll's

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am just trying to create a simple PCL project with MVVM framework but. As I create a PCL project but Its showing me the below error.

[image: Missing Xamarin.Form]

I look into References but Don't know how to get this dll file in my Project.
Below is my Reference dialog.

[image: Click on edit Reference get this dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Did you select the 'Blank Xamarin.Forms App' template when you created your solution? That should have set up the packages for you.

To manually add the Xamarin.Forms package, you can open the dropdown next to 'Packages' in your solution and select 'Add Packages...'. Make sure your package source dropdown is set to 'Official NuGet Gallery' and type 'Xamarin.Forms' in the search box. You can select the Xamarin.Forms package and click 'Add Package'. That should add the reference for you.

You might also have to do this manually in your Android project.

Comment: Yes I have selected  'Blank Xamarin.Forms App' and after project setup all  I found is missing this Xamarin.Form from my project reference,.